# Selecting sibling input box depending on if they've entered details in previous input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code:

```
$.each($('.friendName'), function(){
    if($(this).val() != ''){
        var idName = $(this).attr('id');
        var name = $(this).val();
        var email =  $('#' + idName + ' ~ input').first().val();
        alert(email);
    }
});
```

This code should go through each element with a class of `friendName` (3 input boxes).

Ones that aren't empty, I then want it to find the associated friendEmail input box. For example:

```
friendName1 - friendEmail1
friendName2 - friendEmail2
friendName3 - friendEmail3
```

This should only get results for items that contain details, if only `friendName1` and `friendEmail1` are filled out, it doesn't count the rest of them.

For some reason, I can't get it to get the value of the `friendEmail` input, I'm guessing because it is not a sibling.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you could advance on my code so that it checks to see if each `friendName` and `friendEmail` contain values, then returns them as `var name` and `var email`, that'd be great.

```
<div>
    <label for="friendName1">Friend's Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="friendName1" name="friendName1" class="friendName" value="" />
</div>

<div>
    <label for="friendEmail1">Friend's Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="friendEmail1" name="friendEmail1" value="" />
</div>

<div>
    <label for="friendName2">Friend's Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="friendName2" name="friendName2" class="friendName" value="" />
</div>

<div>
    <label for="friendEmail2">Friend's Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="friendEmail2" name="friendEmail2" class="friendEmail" value="" />
</div>

<div>
    <label for="friendName3">Friend's Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="friendName3" name="friendName3" class="friendName" value="" />
</div>

<div>
    <label for="friendEmail3">Friend's Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="friendEmail3" name="friendEmail3" class="friendEmail" value="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a jsFiddle with an approach http://jsfiddle.net/a2kHt/2/

```
$(function(){
    $(".friendName[value!='']").each(function(){
        var idEmail = 'friendEmail' + $(this).attr("id").replace('friendName','');
        if($("#"+idEmail+"[value!='']").length > 0){
            alert("Name: " + $(this).val() + " - Email: " + $("#"+idEmail).val());
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI,

```
$( '.friendName' ).each( function(){} );
```

also works. ;)

Since you are looping through elements with class '.friendName', you could try it like this:

```
$( '.friendName' ).each( function( index, elem ) {
    if($(this).val() != ''){
         var idName = $(this).attr('id');
        var name = $(this).val();
        var email =  $('#friendMail' + index).first().val();
        console.log( email );
    }
} );
```

Index is the index within the array or in this case, the counter variable, if you want it so. Elem is the element, not wrapped in jQuery.

Btw,

```
console.log( email );
// instead of alert( email );
```

This gives you way more information you can even interact with in FireBug or the built in developer tools in Chrome and IE9.

EDITH:

I too now created an attempt with jsFiddle. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/urnAE/) is what I've come up with. It works. My bad was, that index had to be increased by 1.

Comment: Hey Derija, thanks for your reply. This doesn't seem to work (I've fixed the name of the #friendMail id too) It just logs with undefined. Thank you.